# Read QR code and automatic direct to browser from result

Tags: android, xamarin.android, qr-code, zxing

I recently just started programming and developing app. I would appreciate if anybody can help me.  I had did the QR scanner with ZXing and are able to display the result but i would like it to open the browser automatically if an URL is detected from the QR code

The following is my code for my Scanner Activity:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Views;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Gms.Vision.Barcodes;
using Android.Gms.Vision;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Android;
using static Android.Gms.Vision.Detector;
using Android.Util;

namespace com.xamarin.sample.splashscreen
{
    [Activity(Label = "Scanner")]
    public class Scanner : AppCompatActivity,ISurfaceHolderCallback, IProcessor
    {
        SurfaceView cameraPreview;
        TextView txtResult;
        BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector;
        CameraSource cameraSource;
        const int RequestCameraPermissionID = 1001;

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Permission[] grantResults)
        {
           switch(requestCode)
            {
                case RequestCameraPermissionID:
                    {
                        if (grantResults[0]==Permission.Granted)
                        {
                            if (ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(ApplicationContext, Manifest.Permission.Camera) != Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted)
                            {
                                ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new string[]
                                {
                     Manifest.Permission.Camera
                                 }, RequestCameraPermissionID);
                                return;
                            }
                            try
                            {
                                cameraSource.Start(cameraPreview.Holder);
                            }
                            catch (InvalidOperationException)
                            {

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Scanner);

            cameraPreview = FindViewById<SurfaceView>(Resource.Id.cameraPreview);
            txtResult = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtResult);

            barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this)
                .SetBarcodeFormats(BarcodeFormat.QrCode).Build();

            cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(this, barcodeDetector)
                .SetRequestedPreviewSize(640, 480).Build();

            cameraPreview.Holder.AddCallback(this);
            barcodeDetector.SetProcessor(this);
        }

        public void SurfaceChanged(ISurfaceHolder holder, [GeneratedEnum] Format format, int width, int height)
        {

        }

        public void SurfaceCreated(ISurfaceHolder holder)
        {
          if (ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(ApplicationContext, Manifest.Permission.Camera) != Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted)
                {
                ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new string[]
                {
                     Manifest.Permission.Camera
                 }, RequestCameraPermissionID);
                return;
            }
            try
            {
                cameraSource.Start(cameraPreview.Holder);
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException)
            {

            }
        }

        public void SurfaceDestroyed(ISurfaceHolder holder)
        {
            cameraSource.Stop();
        }

        public void ReceiveDetections(Detections detections)
        {
            SparseArray qrcodes = detections.DetectedItems;
            if(qrcodes.Size()!=0)
            {
                txtResult.Post(() =>
                {
                    Vibrator vib = (Vibrator)GetSystemService(Context.VibratorService);
                    vib.Vibrate(1000);
                    txtResult.Text = ((Barcode)qrcodes.ValueAt(0)).RawValue;
                });
            }
        }

        public void Release()
        {

        }
    }`enter code here`
}`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like it to open the browser automatically if an URL is detected from the QR code

When you get the `ZXing.Result` from the QR code, you could use [Patterns.WebUrl.Matcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Patterns.html) method to confirm whether this is a `URL`.

When you use `Patterns.WebUrl.Matcher(result.Text).Matches()` method, this regular expression pattern to match most part of RFC 3987 Internationalized URLs, aka IRIs.

Code like this :

```
private void HandleScanResult(ZXing.Result result)
    {
        string msg = "";

        if (result != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Text))
            msg = "Found Barcode: " + result.Text;
        else
            msg = "Scanning Canceled!";

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.PutString("result", result.Text);
        resultIntent.PutExtras(bundle);
        this.SetResult(Result.Ok, resultIntent);

        if (Patterns.WebUrl.Matcher(result.Text).Matches())
        {
            //If this result get from the QR code is an URL, open the browse.                    
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.SetAction("android.intent.action.VIEW");
            Android.Net.Uri content_url = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(result.Text);
            intent.SetData(content_url);
            StartActivity(intent);
        }
        else
        {
            this.RunOnUiThread(() => Toast.MakeText(this, msg, ToastLength.Short).Show());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Really appreciate it :)

Comment: It is not working for me yet, still trying to figure out

Comment: @Gideon Ler, what's your problem?

Comment: Like how do i implement the code? i just put the method in Scanner.activity? sorry if i sound dumb, just started with programming ;x

Comment: @Gideon Ler, put the method in Scanner.activity is fine, [here](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/blob/master/Samples/Android/Sample.Android/MainActivity.cs) is an example.

Comment: Hi, i have re-do and used zxing instead but there are a error at  this.SetResult(Result.Ok, resultIntent);   it say that "Result" is an ambiguos reference between 'Android.App.Result' and ZXinng.Result'

Comment: "Result" is an ambiguos reference between 'Android.App.Result' and ZXinng.Result'

Comment: @Gideon Ler, the message means you should use  `Android.App.Result` instead of  `ZXinng.Result`, modify your code like this : `this.SetResult(Android.App.Result.Ok, resultIntent)`.

Comment: @Gideon Ler, please include the build error log, this will easier to troubleshooting this issue.

Comment: @Gideon Ler, happy coding. : -)